# How to get all existing images src in this url with PHP?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

There are 6 images in this url which I want to give src images. My goal is getting all images src with PHP but only one image src coming.

```
<?php
require_once ('simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://www.zara.com/tr/en/flatform-derby-shoes-with-reversible-fringe-p15318201.html?v1=5276035&v2=734142');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
     echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: My guess would be that Simple HTML DOM has issues with `src`'s that doesn't contain an actual URL (specially after reading the bug tracker). Only one of the images actually has a URL in the `src`. The rest has `src="data:image/png;base64,...."` (inline images). Have you tried using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you should submit that as an actual answer...

Comment: @anarcat Done. I just wanted to include a working example with proper comments.

Comment: You might want to switch to [this](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) - it fixes this issue and lots of other ones.

Comment: @pguardiario you don't need any "drop-in replacement for PHP's simple html dom library". SimpleHtmlDom should just die. All you need is DOM and XPath.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the `Simple HTML DOM` bug tracker. It seems like they are having some issues fetching values that aren't real URL's.

Looking at the source of the page you're trying to fetch, only one image actually does have a URL. The rest has inline images: `src="data:image/png;base64,..."`.

I would suggest using PHP's own [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this.

Here's a working solution (with comments):

```
<?php
// Get the HTML from the URL
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.zara.com/tr/en/flatform-derby-shoes-with-reversible-fringe-p15318201.html?v1=5276035&v2=734142");

$doc = new DOMDocument;
// DOMDocument throws a bunch of errors since the HTML isn't 100% valid 
// (and for all HTML5-tags) but it will sort them out. 
// Let's just tell it to fix it in silence.
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc->loadHTML($data);

libxml_clear_errors();

// Fetch all img-tags and get the 'src' attributes.
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    echo $img->getAttribute('src') . '<br />';
}
```

Demo: https://www.tehplayground.com/sh4yJ8CqIwypwkCa

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for pointing out that there was no need for `PHP Tidy` (Since DOMDocumnet will sort out the invalid HTML).

Comment: i want give src images of shoes in this url but with your codes not coming src images of shoes

Comment: @mohammadsaber - That's most likely because they aren't rendering the images in the HTML but rather through some Javascript/Ajax on page load. That's a completely different and much more complex question. This was about getting all images, which you do get. It does seem like 5 of them (the inline image data) are just blank png's.

Answer (score 0):

Actually those base64encodes are the images [base64ecnoded images](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/base64-images.html). As far as this page you want to parse although the images are base64 encoded the a tags that are the parents of the images actually are containing the image urls.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.zara.com/tr/en/flatform-derby-shoes-with-reversible-fringe-p15318201.html?v1=5276035&v2=734142");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

and now the data manipulation

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$siteData = new DOMDocument();
$siteData->loadHTML($data);

$a = $siteData->getElementsByTagName("a"); //get the a tags
for($i=0;$i<$a->length;$i++){
    if($a->item($i)->getAttribute("class")=="_seoImg"){ //_seoImg class   is the image class
       echo $a->item($i)->getAttribute("href").'<br/>';
    }
}
```

and the result is

```
//static.zara.net/photos///2017/I/1/1/p/5318/201/040/3/w/560/5318201040_2_1_1.jpg?ts=1508311623896
//static.zara.net/photos///2017/I/1/1/p/5318/201/040/3/w/560/5318201040_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1508311816920
//static.zara.net/photos///2017/I/1/1/p/5318/201/040/3/w/560/5318201040_2_3_1.jpg?ts=1508311715728
//static.zara.net/photos///2017/I/1/1/p/5318/201/040/3/w/560/5318201040_2_10_1.jpg?ts=1508315639664
//static.zara.net/photos///2017/I/1/1/p/5318/201/040/3/w/560/5318201040_2_2_1.jpg?ts=1508311682567
```